# \r does not generate a line break

Tags: java, string

I use the following code:

```
if (delanaloge.equals(stari)) {
    if (novi.equals("-")) {
           zdruzen = " -";
    } else {
       zdruzen = zdruzen + " " + " - " + novi + "\r";
    }
    nap = true;
 }
```

`\r` is appended to create a line break, but it does not generate a line break like I expect. I would like to generate an output similar to this:

```
- 213
- 232
- 1321
```

How can I add a line break in my string?

Comment: have you tried '\n'? for os dependent new line you ca use String osNewLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

Comment: i try \n is the same and \r\n too. It is not like enter button

Comment: Are you talking about paragraph breaks in microsoft word, done by pressing the enter key?

Comment: \r is carriage return and \n is linebreak. Clearly you need both to advance to the next line and be in the first position.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

you could use this:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: Awesome! Works in Android dialog windows ;)

Comment: thanks, good to know, Java seems to consequently follow this on all platforms :)

Comment: Works for me too! Thanks. When is text hardcoded in project \n works well, but when coming from Retrofit needs of System.getPrope....

Answer (score 9):

New line character combinations vary between OS. Windows is `\r\n`, Unix-like systems such as Linux, FreeBSD, Android and so on is `\n` and MacOS is `\r`.

Try whichever suits your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (delanaloge.equals(stari)) {
    if (novi.equals("-")) {
        zdruzen = " -";
    } else {
        zdruzen = zdruzen + "  - " + novi + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    nap = true;
}
```

Comment: this is good idea but - and then new line is not the same as if you in word click labeling. I try to make labeling

Answer (score 0):

try to use \r\n, in some cases \n will work (or every case) .. just try both :)

Comment: i try \n is the same and \r\n too. It is not like enter button

Answer (score 0):

In `JTextPane` and other text components `\n` suffices and seems a good choice. On Windows the document internally stores `\r\n` so document positions and `getText()` indices are not equal. `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is more correct, but `\n` is so universal.

Answer (score 0):

Use \ n for line breaking in printing the String.

```
if (delanaloge.equals(stari)) {
if (novi.equals("-")) {
       zdruzen = " -";
} else {
   zdruzen = zdruzen + " " + " - " + novi + "\n";
}
nap = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit from the typing machines age -

- \r is the carriage return and should go back to the line origin.
- \n is the new line feed on and does create the new line.

For Windows systems \r\n is a typical new line - and works as on the typing machine - carriage return, then new line.

For Linux based systems it was shorten to just \n. But '\n' is normally recognized by most programs.