# Java - Output Lines

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a way of creating a line in the output after its run,

code is

```
int topScore = 80;
        if (topScore < 100) {
            System.out.println("You got the high score!");
        }
        int secondTopScore = 60;
        if (topScore > secondTopScore && topScore < 100) {
            System.out.println("Greater than second top score and less than 100");
        }

        //Video 36 - Logical OR Operator

        int topScore1 = 80;
        if (topScore1 < 100) {
            System.out.println("You got the high score!");
        }
        int secondTopScore1 = 81;
        if ((topScore1 > secondTopScore1) && (topScore1 < 100)) {
            System.out.println("Greater than second top score and less than 100");
        }
```

Output is

```
   You got the high score!
   Greater than second top score and less than 100
   You got the high score!
```

However I want it to have a blank space link this

```
You got the high score!
Greater than second top score and less than 100
**Blank Line
You got the high score!
```

I have tried \n but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\r does not generate a line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093765/r-does-not-generate-a-line-break)

Comment: [System.out.println();](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `\n` to the beginning of the string

```
  int topScore = 80;
    if (topScore < 100) {
        System.out.println("\nYou got the high score!");
    }
    int secondTopScore = 60;
    if (topScore > secondTopScore && topScore < 100) {
        System.out.println("Greater than second top score and less than 100");
    }

    //Video 36 - Logical OR Operator

    int topScore1 = 80;
    if (topScore1 < 100) {
        System.out.println("\nYou got the high score!");
    }
    int secondTopScore1 = 81;
    if ((topScore1 > secondTopScore1) && (topScore1 < 100)) {
        System.out.println("Greater than second top score and less than 100");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `println` without arguments

```
System.out.println()
```